# Как исправить ошибку о том что переменная не присвоена?

Tags: python, sql, bs4, pymysql

Есть скрипт:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

# < Сбор ссылок.
def get_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links=soup.findAll(link_container_array[0],{link_container_array[1]:link_container_array[2]})
    for link_container in links:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
             link = resource_allnews_link + a_tag.get("href")
    return link
# < Сбор контента.
def get_content(html, link):
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
     page_url=soup.find(page_link_array[0],{page_link_array[1]:page_link_array[2]})
     print(page_url)
#< Вызывание всех функций.
def main(resource_allnews_link):
    url = resource_allnews_link
    get_links(get_html(url))
    get_content(link)

# < Подключение к базе данных.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='news_portal',
                             charset='utf8',
                             autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# < Запрос правил выдергивания контента.
cursor.execute('SELECT `resource_id`, `resource_name`, `resource_url`, `resource_allnews_link`, `link_rule`, `mainblock`, `mainblock1`, `page_link`, `title`, `datetime`, `datetime1`, `text`, `text1` FROM `resource` WHERE 1')
resources=cursor.fetchall()
# < Цикл для перебора из кортежа.
for resource in resources:
    resource_allnews_link=resource[3]
    content_rule=resource[4]
    main_block=resource[5]
    main_block1=resource[6]
    page_link=resource[7]
    title=resource[8]
    datetime=resource[9]
    datetime1=resource[10]
    text=resource[11]
    text1=resource[12]
    link_container_array=content_rule.split(',')
    main_block_array=main_block.split(',')
    main_block1_array=main_block1.split(',')
    page_link_array=page_link.split(',')
    title_array=title.split(',')
    datetime=datetime.split(',')
    datetime1=datetime1.split(',')
    text=text.split(',')
    text1=text1.split(',')

    main(resource_allnews_link)

connection.close()
```

И при запуске скрипта выходит такая ошибка что переменная `link` не присвоена.Хотя я в функции `get_links` сделал `return`.

Вот текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/sql_parser.py", line 64, in <module>
    main(resource_allnews_link)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/sql_parser.py", line 28, in main
    get_content(link)
NameError: name 'link' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Нужно взять учебник и перечитать главы о функциях, области видимости переменных и смежные. Ваше return link не создаёт переменную link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно переписать функцию вот так. У вас кроме того нарушено количество параметров у функции  get_content.

```
def main(resource_allnews_link):
    url = resource_allnews_link
    link=get_links(get_html(url))
    get_content(get_html(url),link)
```

Comment: Можно переписать ещё лучше и сократить количество строк. Первая - ненужна.

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто возвращаете значение, а не выводите переменную.
Т.е. ваша запись равносильна

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
```

Самое простое что тут можно сделать - присваивать возвращаемые значения переменным.

```
def main(resource_allnews_link):
    link = get_links(get_html(resource_allnews_link))
    get_content(link)
```